# What happens when you are at $r=2M$ distance from a $M$ mass black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, event-horizon

I was reading this question:

[Are gravitational time dilation and the time dilation in special relativity independent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63070/)

And JohnRennie's answer: (sorry for the syntax in  formulas, I don't know how to make them look good)

> Now consider general relativity, and the effect of gravity. But first let me rewrite the special relativity equation for the line element in polar co-ordinates:
>
> $$\mathrm  ds^2 = -\mathrm dt^2 +\mathrm  dr^2 + r^2 (\mathrm d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta~\mathrm d\phi^2) $$
>
> and now I'll write the equation for the line element near a black hole, i.e. the Schwarzschild metric:
>
> $$ \mathrm ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\mathrm dt^2 + \frac{\mathrm dr^2}{\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)} + r^2 (\mathrm d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta~\mathrm  d\phi^2) $$

Question:

So what happens when the mass M and   the distance are set so that 2M/r=1? If you are at r=2M distance from a M mass black hole then (1-2M/r)=0 and what will that mean?

This  will be zero −(1−2Mr)dt2.

And this will be infinite dr2(1−2Mr).

What does that mean?

Comment: The region $r=2M$ is called the event horizon. We (and the web at large) already have a wealth of information about that, so could you be a bit more specific about what you want to know about it?

Comment: R=0 is the true singularity. Why do we call the event horizon a coordinate singularity? And specifically, what does it mean that this will be zero −(1−2Mr)dt2. CountTO10 says "The correspondence between the Schwarzchild metric and the flat scale metric implies that the the time coordinate used here is the same as the time coordinate used by a distant. observer." What does that mean? The time will pass at the same rate as for a distant observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what happens when the mass M and the distance are set so that $2M/r=1$? If you are at $r=2M$ distance from a $M$ mass black hole then $(1-2M/r)=0$ and what will that mean? This will be zero $−(1−2Mr)dt^2$.

The correspondence between the Schwarzchild metric and the flat scale metric implies that  the the time coordinate used here $t$ is the same as the time coordinate used by a distant. observer.

> And this will be infinite $dr^2(1−2M/r)$.

When $r$ equals $2m$, you get a singularity, the value of $r$ that causes this is the Schwarzchild radius, in the case of the Sun, this is deep inside the body of the Sun, about 3 Km from the core.

What you must do is ensure that  this is not a singularity caused by your choice of coordinates, remember  you can use any coordinate, but it would make sense to use  the  most convenient one.

The method used to check for coordinate singularites is is to calculate, 
$$R_{abcd}R^{abcd} = \frac {48m^2}{r^6} $$

At $r =0$, this is still a singularity, a scalar that is the same in all systems, so it's a true singularity.

> What do you mean by $r=2M$ is a coordinate singularity (metric becomes singular) but not a true singularity (no invariants blow up)" What does that mean? what is a true singularity then?

From ACuriousMind's comment below:

> What you get at $r=2M$ is a coordinate singularity (metric becomes singular) but not a true singularity (no invariants blow up). There are other coordinates in which the metric remains finite, the event horizon is not a true singularity, although it is a region of some significance. The only true singularity in the Schwarzschild case is located at the center of the black hole $r = 2M$ is precisely the location of the event horizon of the black hole.

Comment: Careful: What you get at $r=2M$ is a *coordinate singularity* (metric becomes singular) but *not* a *true singularity* (no invariants blow up). There are other coordinates in which the metric remains finite, the event horizon is *not* a true singularity, although it *is* a region of some significance. The only true singularity in the Schwarzschild case is located at the center of the black hole. That is also missing from the answer: The value $r=2M$ is precisely the location of the event horizon of the black hole.

Comment: I voted this as favorite, but please explain more the first part. This will be zero −(1−2Mr)dt2. You say  "The correspondence between the Schwarzchild metric and the flat scale metric implies that the the time coordinate used here is the same as the time coordinate used by a distant. observer." What does this mean?

Comment: what do you mean by "r=2M  is a coordinate singularity (metric becomes singular) but not a true singularity (no invariants blow up)" What does that mean? what is a true singularity then?

Comment: Hi Árpád, sorry for the delay in writing back, (I have arthritis so I just can't type that fast). Are you happy with the answer, I would ask you to read through it, for your first question, there are two times involved here, the time $t$ measured by anybody far away, also called the coordinate time, and the time $\tau $, which is the time measured by an observer near the black hole, also called proper time. In this case they match.

Answer (score 3):

> What does that mean?

It *means* that for $r \gt 2M$, an infinitesimal displacement $\mathrm{d}r$ is *space-like* while for $r \lt 2M$, an infinitesimal displacement $\mathrm{d}r$ is *time-like*.  The horizon is the boundary.

Put another way, inside the horizon, moving *forward* in time means decreasing in $r$, i.e., for the same reason that we move forward in time, one must move toward $r = 0$ once inside the horizon.