# Does the clock tick faster when falling?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, time-dilation, observers

I just read this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63070/are-gravitational-time-dilation-and-the-time-dilation-in-special-relativity-inde) that explains that the time dilation due to the gravity and the time dilation due to velocity are the same thing.

Does that mean that, if I fall from the top of a skyscraper on Earth, my clock ticks faster than the clock of an observer that remains at the top of the skyscraper because even though I'm moving faster than him, my body is motionless in the space component of space-time?

In other words, does this gravitational/velocity time dilation equivalence implies that any observers subject to gravity (not falling) is actually moving in the space component of space-time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A clock in freefall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130323/)

Comment: Wouldn't your clock tick slower?

Comment: My reasoning is: if time slows down because of gravity, then a clock subject to 1g on the surface of the Earth would tick slower than a clock subject to 0g in freefall.

Comment: Oh, you're ignoring the motion of the clock and focusing on the difference in gravity?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking: if the 2 time dilations are the same thing then it means a clock at 1g is moving in space, even though it doesn't look like it's moving at all on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks, I wish it would answer my question but I'm afraid I don't have the physics background to get my answer from the equations provided.